# AEC in Flash, getEnhancedMicrophone

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, aec

Have next problem:

```
var mic:Microphone = Microphone.getEnhancedMicrophone();
mic.setLoopBack(true);
```

And I don`t hear any sound... What is it?
When I write Microphone.getMicrophone() all work right and I hear sounds.

Answer (score 1):

To work around it, try the following steps:

1) install [debug player](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) 10.3 or higher

*It's very likely that you run it with NOT debug version of flash player, that is why you miss important warnings and exceptions.*

2) allow users to accept access to the microphone:

```
Security.showSettings("2");
```

3) compile a SWF with following option:

```
-swf-version=12
```

*To use new features in 10.3, you have to publish the SWF to target "Flash Player 11". Otherwise getEnhancedMicrophone() function won't be visible.*

---

[EDIT]

To make it work in Adobe Flash CS5 you need to:

3.1) go to

```
${FLASH_CS5_HOME}\Common\Configuration\ActionScript 3.0
```

3.2) create a new folder with the name `FP10.3`

3.3) copy the file and paste it in the following location:

```
${FLASH_CS5_HOME}\Common\Configuration\ActionScript 3.0\FP10.3
```

3.4) rename the swc name to `playerglobal.swc`

3.5) go to

```
${FLASH_CS5_HOME}\Common\Configuration\Players
```

3.6) create a copy of `FlashPlayer10_1.xml` and rename as `FlashPlayer10_3.xml`

3.7) open it in an editor and change according to below:

```
<player id="FlashPlayer10.3" version="12" asversion="3">
   <name>Flash Player 10.3</name>
   <path builtin="true"/>
   <path platform="WIN">Device Central/adcdl.exe</path>
   <path platform="MAC">Device Central/adcdl</path>
   <playerDefinitionPath as2="$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP10;$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP9;$(UserConfi g)/Classes/FP8;$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP7" as3="$(AppConfig)/ActionScript 3.0/FP10.3/playerglobal.swc" />
```

3.8) close the flash application if launched and restart the flash application

3.9) if you promptly followed everything you will Flash player 10.3 in the target players from the publish settings and change your target to `Flash Player 10.3`

3.10) now import two statements:

```
      import flash.media.Microphone;
      import flash.media.MicrophoneEnhancedMode;
```

[/EDIT]

---

Example:

```
public function init():void {
    var mic:Microphone = Microphone.getEnhancedMicrophone();
    Security.showSettings("2");
    mic.setLoopBack(true);
    if (mic != null) {
        mic.setSilenceLevel(0);
        mic.rate = 16;
        mic.addEventListener(ActivityEvent.ACTIVITY, activityHandler);
        mic.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, statusHandler);
    }
}

private function activityHandler(event:ActivityEvent):void {
    trace("activityHandler: " + event);
}

private function statusHandler(event:StatusEvent):void {
    trace("statusHandler: " + event);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @KwI, any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you set the swf version? -swf-version=12? I am using Adobe Flash CS5

Comment: @Joy, you need to create `FlashPlayer10_3.xml`. Try to make changes to your Adobe Flash CS5 configuration according to the answer.

Comment: I have done all that and yet getting some error. I have posted my question here as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058073/targeting-flash-player-10-3-in-adobe-flash-cs5