# Best Echo Cancellation in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, aec

What is the best way to do Acoustic Echo Cancellation (AEC) for a Flash video chat application (that uses RTMP)? Any example code please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried targeting Flash Player 10.3 and using the getEnhancedMicrophone() method?

Comment: Yes I tried, but I got lost.. is it only applicable under Flex? Whenever I try it using Adobe Flash CS5.5 it keeps telling me that the function is not recognized..

Comment: Apparently, the problem is that you need to compile your swf using some arguments like -swf - version=12, CS5 doesn't let you pass these arguments and hence, you got to use FLEX, just to compile your swf. Even I am working on it. Would write back if I could make it work successfully.

Comment: Thanks! Waiting to see if you can make it work well.. I am totally new to Flex although I have it installed and played around with the MXML.. yet it is hard to redo the whole thing using it.. also I am not sure how I can import a regular FLA file into the Adobe Flash Builder and then use Flex to cover these "missing" functionality.. would be great if you can guide me! Thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear: I could get the thing to work with Flex, but was lost when it comes to integrating that to my already made thing on Adobe Flash CS5.5.. is there a way to import the "FLA" file and then add that flex libraries into it using Adobe Flash Builder? Is there a step by step guide? So, I have the getEnhancedMicrophone() example working on Flex (Adobe Flash Builder), and I have my own chat application done on Adobe Flash CS5.5 (FLA file).. how can I now integrate both using Adobe Builder/Flex without the effort of redoing things using MXML?

Comment: Here is the solution to the problem of how you can still do it from within Adobe CS5.5 Professional: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581453/aec-in-flash-getenhancedmicrophone

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start [here](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/448445) it contains pointers to examples, open issues etc.