# How to import FLA and include Flex into it using Flash Builder to get it to compile with getEnhancedMicrophone()?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, adobe, flash-builder

I am trying to do the following, can you please guide/help me do it:

I have a video chat application that is done on Adobe Flash CS5.5. I had the problem of "echo" so I wanted to use "getEnhancedMicrophone()". When I replaced "getMicrophone()" with "getEnhancedMicrophone()", Adobe Flash CS5.5 Professional didn't recognize it. I knew I need Flex, so I installed Flash Builder. And then got lost. What I simply want is just import my "FLA" file (or if I need to convert it to something else using a specific tool, let me know.. I have Adobe Flash CS5.5 Professional and can install other required applications if needed) done on Adobe CS5.5, into Flash Builder, and then "support Flex" so that I compile with the flash-version argument required.

I am totally new to MXML and Flash Builder, and even Flex. I don't know how to import a FLA and add "Flex" libraries into it simply to make "getEnhancedMicrophone()" work without the need to recreate the whole thing on Flash Builder. Can you guide me please? The output is for a web SWF file, not a desktop application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Flash Pro CS5 on a Mac and I did the following to use Flex features like the Embed tag. Not sure if it will solve your problem too, but its worth a try.

1. Go to the Plash Pro Preferences Window
2. Click on "ActionScript" tab
3. Click on "ActionScript 3.0 Settings..." Button
4. Click the "Browse to SWC file" icon in the "Library Path" section
5. Browse to flex.swc and click open

If you are on a Mac flex.swc should be located here:

/Applications/Adobe Flash CS5/Common/Configuration/ActionScript 3.0/flex_sdk/4.0.0/frameworks/libs/flex.swc

Not sure about Windows. It will look a little different of course, because you are using CS5.5

To get an idea on how to create a Flash Professional Projects inside Flash Builder you might want to check out this help site from Adobe:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WSc5cd04c102ae3e97-6e5d439512e1414e588-7fff.html

Comment: Let me test and get back to you :-)

Comment: I tried it but faced some problems.. but I think if I tested on another computer it would work.. however, this is what worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581453/aec-in-flash-getenhancedmicrophone